# Weird scrolling effect caused by overflow: hidden on body, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I disable `overflow: hidden;` on my body, html adds some sort of crop at the bottom of the screen. If I have it enabled I also can't get the scroll-to-top button to work.

Is there any way I can fix this or maybe have the grid scroll affect the button reveal? Also the arrow key scrolling doesn't seem to work as well on the grid div. Hope you guys can help!

```html
body, html {
  overflow: hidden; /*scrolling problem*/
  height: 100%;
}
```

Full code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("backTop").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("backTop").style.opacity = "0";
  }
}


function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden; /*scrolling problem*/
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-div {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}

.mid-div {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(90px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px;
}

  .grid-item {
    position: relative;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    background-color: red;
  }

    .span-wide {
        grid-column-end: span 2;
        grid-row-end: span 2;
    }
    
    .span-long {
        grid-column-end: span 1;
        grid-row-end: span 4;
    }

.right-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}

  #backTop {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div"></div>
  
  <div class="mid-div">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item span-wide"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item span-long"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item span-long"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right-div">
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="backTop" title="Back to Top">Top</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: body has 1em margin which you need to reset to 0 . this is a default value. https://jsfiddle.net/drjqws4z/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the padding and margin from the body:

```
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

and adjust the height of the mid-div to be 100vh minus the height of a scrollbar:

```
.mid-div {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

I've updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bjqLmswz/

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your mid-div

```
  <div id="midDiv" class="mid-div">
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item span-wide"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item span-long"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item span-long"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
```

And then modify scrollFunction()

```
    document.getElementById("midDiv").onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById("midDiv").scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("backTop").style.opacity = "1";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("backTop").style.opacity = "0";
      }

}
```